# Add unique column when I have condition

Tags: sql, oracle, unique-index

I have table these are the field of the table

```
project_labor
PROJECT_NO, LABOR_ID, STATUS
```

the status field has two values which are(complete or in complete)
if the value of status is (complete) labor id can be repeated
but if the status value is (incomplete) labor id have to be unique

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use function index(by default `NULL` value for single column index are skipped):

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IX_name 
ON project_labor (CASE WHEN STATUS='complete' THEN NULL ELSE LABOR_ID END);
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=cb41dce22cda9e84f960b32015d87e50)**

Full script:

```
CREATE TABLE project_labor(PROJECT_NO INT, LABOR_ID INT, STATUS VARCHAR2(10));

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IX_name 
ON project_labor (CASE WHEN STATUS='complete' THEN NULL ELSE labor_id END);

INSERT INTO project_labor(project_no,status,labor_id) VALUES(1, 'uncomplete', 1);
INSERT INTO project_labor(project_no,status,labor_id) VALUES(2, 'uncomplete', 1);
-- ORA-00001: unique constraint (IX_NAME) violated

INSERT INTO project_labor(project_no,status,labor_id) VALUES(3, 'complete', 2)
INSERT INTO project_labor(project_no,status,labor_id) VALUES(4, 'complete', 2)

SELECT * FROM project_labor
```

It is a equivalent of partial index from other RDBMS:

[PostgreSQL - partial index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/indexes-partial.html) / [SQLite - Partial index](https://www.sqlite.org/partialindex.html) / [SQL Server - filtered index](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/create-filtered-indexes?view=sql-server-2017)